# Link library in ParaView plugin CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, cmake, paraview

Recently I've been trying to write a plugin for ParaView and I have encountered a problem while trying to link external libraries. First of all I must say that the compilation goes fine but I get an error at runtime saying the dreaded words: "symbol lookup error .. undefined symbol".

When using ldd on the file that I load into ParaView, none of the vxl library files that are required for this plugin are listed. ParaView has it's own weird way of defining plugins in the CmakeLists.txt file and this is why it's so hard for me to find information on how to link this library properly.

My CMakeLists.txt looks as follows now:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
IF (ParaView_SOURCE_DIR)
  INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
    ${VTK_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  )
ELSE (ParaView_SOURCE_DIR)
  FIND_PACKAGE(ParaView REQUIRED)
  INCLUDE(${PARAVIEW_USE_FILE})
ENDIF (ParaView_SOURCE_DIR)

FIND_PACKAGE(VXL)

IF(VXL_FOUND)
  INCLUDE(${VXL_CMAKE_DIR}/UseVXL.cmake)
ENDIF(VXL_FOUND)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${VXLCORE_INCLUDE_DIR})

ADD_PARAVIEW_PLUGIN(Main "0.0"
  SERVER_MANAGER_XML Main.xml
SERVER_MANAGER_SOURCES Main.cxx LSModelFit.cxx 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't obvious, but you should be able to just add a library to the `Main` target that `add_paraview_plugin` defines with

`target_link_libraries(Main vxl)`

or whatever the library name is.

Comment: I found it by now, but for anyone wondering, this is exactly what solved it.