# Resolve dependencies of paraview plugin

Tags: cmake, shared-libraries, paraview

**The situation, I'm starting with:**

I compiled Paraview on my development PC without problems.
I then compiled some small plugin for it - again with out problems.
If I run Paraview (either my compiled version or the binaries from the webpage) on that PC, I can load and use the plugin.

**The problem:**

I did not find a way, how to get the plugin to run on other computers using the Paraview binaries.

When I run ldd on the plugin .so file, it tells me that it can't find a list of Pparaview libraries, which are supplied with the binary:

```
libvtkPVClientServerCoreCore-pv5.4.so.1 => not found
libvtkCommonExecutionModel-pv5.4.so.1 => not found
libvtkCommonDataModel-pv5.4.so.1 => not found
libvtkClientServer-pv5.4.so.1 => not found
libvtkCommonCore-pv5.4.so.1 => not found
```

Obviously, the plugin depends on Paraview libraries (makes sense so far), which it can't find. Now I should admit, that Paraview was no really installed on the Linux system, but just downloaded as binary distribution. I'm aware of the common library search paths in Linux. My problem is now, this plugin was developed to be used by a group of users, I don't have direct relations with. They will download Paraview somehow and get it to run. I can't rely on them putting the binary into the correct path to find the libraries.

Is there a way, how to statically link these libraries with the plugin (although this is completely against the idea of having shared libs)? Any Cmake defines, I'm missing?

I found this similar thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35971739/link-library-in-paraview-plugin-cmakelists-txt), but I couldn't really make use out of that.

Comment: `Is there a way, how to statically link these libraries with the plugin` - You need *static libraries* for being able to link them statically. I am not expert with Paraview, but [it seems](https://www.paraview.org/Wiki/ParaView:Build_And_Install) you can build it with static libraries by using `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF` option to `cmake`.

Comment: Thank you for replying! I know that I could compile paraview itself in a different way. But I need my plugin to work with the paraview version as it is supplied from the webpage.

Comment: `I need my plugin to work with the paraview version as it is supplied from the webpage.` - And, as far as I understand your situation, ParaView supplied from the webpage can be changed when it evolves, am I rigth? If so, you need to link with dynamic libraries, and should find these libraries on the customer PC. That means, if a customer puts libraries into non-system directory, he/she should adjust environment variables so these libraries could be found. This situation is usual for any libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a solution to the above problem in the mean time:

After all, the missing libraries were only a symptom. I did compile Paraview using the superbuild scripts from their webpage https://gitlab.kitware.com/paraview/paraview-superbuild, still without success. The key to compile a plugin that works with the binaries from the webpage is to use the same compiler version (and probably libc etc.).

I did use the PV_PLUGIN_DEBUG variable to troubleshoot the plugin only to find out that it crashed during the debug output. Obviously, Paraview tried to jump to certain addresses to call some introspection functions (e.g. returning a list of plugin dependencies, which happened to be an empty string in my case), but the functions were not found at this address.

To cut things short: You need to get **CentOS** 6 using the **devtools-4** package to compile both Paraview (to get the libraries and includes) and your plugin. Then things suddenly work as they should.

Comment: I am having the very same problem like you had. Only in my case it is that my plugin has a `libvtknetcdf` dependency which is not present in the binary paraview version. I built the paraview superbuild with `-DENABLE_qt5` and `-DENABLE_python`. What flags did you use for your paraview compilation?

Comment: I used ccmake and I have ENABLE_Qt5, ENABLE_paraviewsdk, ENABLE_netcdf and ENABLE_vtkm set to on. This generates amongst others a libnetcdf.so and a libvtkm_cont.so within the install/lib directory. Does that help you?

Comment: If I use `ENABLE_qt5` and `ENABLE_paraviewsdk` the error message `Please use a system qt5 or disable qt5 to enable SDK deployment!` pops up. I chose `qt5` and will see if this works.

Comment: Correct, USE_SYSTEM_qt5 is also on. I then did pass -DQt5_DIR=path_to_qt to cmake. This may actually only work upon the first call to cmake or ccmake. If so, you have to delete CMakeCache.txt and CMakeFiles before you re-run it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of different ways to get it to work based on the way it was compiled.

My first recommendation would be to try setting your LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable in the shell that you are launching Paraview from. You already know the directory containing the libraries it is trying to load, so run the command `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=\path\to\libs:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before launching Paraview.

Secondly you could overwrite the rpath contained in the binary to point to the location of the shared libs. The best way to do this is with patchelf. Their webpage shows you exactly how to do it here: https://github.com/NixOS/patchelf . This however modifies the binary, so I would still recommend LD_LIBRARY_PATH as the first option.

Answer (score 0):

It's not impossible, but you need to build ParaView exactly the same way as the official binaries with the exactly same compilers, service, packs, etc. That is needed to ensure your plugins run with the "official" binaries.

Ideally, ParaView would provide an SDK against which you could build plugins that would work with the official binaries, but that is not available. Until an SDK is available (no known ETA), you'll need to package and provide your own ParaView binaries to make your plugin work. ParaView superbuild makes this reasonably easy. See https://gitlab.kitware.com/paraview/paraview-superbuild. Or you can inquire on the *paraview-developers@paraview.org* mailing list to see what the exact build configuration for a platform and ParaView version is and try to replicate the build.